# Unzip files into a new directory

Tags: zip

I am using Manjaro Gnu/Linux and have a problem. I have a directory named `files`, and under this directory, I have around 650 zip files, with names such as:
file1.zip, file2.zip, file3.zip,...

I want to write a command/script to automatically unzip all of the '.zip' files into a sub-directory, having the same name as the zip file. For example, 'file1.zip' file's contents should be unzipped into a sub-directory called 'file1', 'file2.zip' file's contents should be unzipped into a sub-directory called 'file2' and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a simple `for` loop with a glob expression iterating over your input `zip` files and unzip them with extension removed

```
for file in *.zip; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    unzip "$file" -d "${file%%.zip}"
done
```